# Why is this syntax incorrect for python?

Tags: python, django, debugging, terminal

I am working on a wiki look-a-like page and it is saying that this is incorrect but there is nothing seemingly incorrect about it. [here is the 'error'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asAmB.png)

when attempting to run the server I got this response from the terminal
[terminal response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZzcf.png)

I am trying to figure out all of my issues so that I am able to run the server and look at the website. Can anyone help me understand why there is an issue? Any help is appreciate and any clarification can be provided upon request.

**this is the code straight from the editor(below)**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
import random
import re

from . import util
from markdown2 import Markdown
```

Comment: What version of python are you running?

Comment: just `import util`

Comment: Please attach screenshots as images, as not as links. Did you add `markdown2` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: I attached the images in the way that was formatted by stack overflow, i am not aware of any other way. I recently added markdown2 so that i fix that problem however it's still showing different parts are invalid syntax but it was correct before so im not understanding

Answer (score 0):

Sunnyday...the mistake is from how you are passing in the context to be rendered.

the function view should be:

```
def index(request):
    context={'entries': util.list_entries(),
    'title':"Home",
     'heading' :"All Pages"}
     return render(request,'templateName.html',context)
```